# complex sql query in rails and displaying results as a grid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

lets say i have a long sql query with a few selects and merges. I don't want to start writing the ActiveRecord code for it because its in use only by me. and only once every few weeks (its like a report) I just want to run the query, get the results and display them, as is.

I am new to rails, used to ASP.Net and MVC 3
is there anything I can use for the view that will just render a table off of the query result?

thanks

Comment: Any code that you tried?

Comment: no.. i don't really know rails. I have an sql query.
just asking how you run it in rails.

Comment: build a simple view based on the output of your sql query. This is more than easy in rails. If you have direct access to the database, why do you need rails. You can use ASP.Net or whatever you want for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute raw SQL from within ActiveRecord without needing to bind a class to a table:

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(@db).connection.execute("select * from teh_tables")
p result.to_yaml
```

You can then either result.to_yaml, result.inspect or pass result to FasterCSV to generate a CSV file for further analysis in Excel or your spreadsheet of choice.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html

You can use `to_a` to view an array of key/value pairs.

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('SELECT id, title, body FROM posts')
p result.to_a
```